# Spring boot is not being deployed on tomcat with this error

Tags: tomcat, gradle, spring-boot, deployment, war

Good day :]

I have problem with deploying with these errors.

Here is some information from catalina.out

```
15-May-2017 15:41:34.376 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M21
15-May-2017 15:41:34.388 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/root/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M21/webapps/makerscout-0.7.war]
15-May-2017 15:41:35.500 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
15-May-2017 15:42:27.566 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [52,024] milliseconds.
15-May-2017 15:42:27.601 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/root/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M21/webapps/makerscout-0.7.war] has finished in [53,213] ms
```

Tomcat9 / Spring-boot / Gradle / JAVA 1.8 (linux / eclipse)

Here is my whole line from build.gradle

```
buildscript 
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    javaVersion = '1.8'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
}
}
version = '0.7'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'application'

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina:8.0.43'
}

sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
targetCompatibility = javaVersion

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'){
    exclude module: "tomcat-embed-el"
}
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'){
    exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:3.0.0.RELEASE')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile('org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf:3.0.0.RELEASE')
compile('org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4:3.0.0.RELEASE')
runtime('com.h2database:h2')
runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
compile("org.springframework:spring-websocket:4.1.6.RELEASE")
compile("org.springframework:spring-messaging:4.1.6.RELEASE")
compile("com.navercorp.lucy:lucy-xss:1.6.3")
compile("com.navercorp.lucy:lucy-xss-servlet:2.0.0")
compile("org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:4.2")

}
```

I don't know why this application is not being launched on tomcat.
Some people adviced this problem comes from 'version incorrect between server / client'. But both place has JAVA 1.8 version identically.

Thank you very much.
I'll keep finding solution for this.

Comment: Out of interest, how come you're using SpringBoot, with its own Tomcat instance, and compiling into a .war file to run on another instance of Tomcat?

Comment: I'm compiling into war file and run on tomcat (on linux server)

Comment: Is it your own server, or are you forced to deploy on a specific environment because that's how they are doing it in your place of work? If it's your own server and you have full say over how things are deployed, you do know you can just run a SpringBoot app as a runnable jar?

Comment: I'm working on this in linux (terminal) :] but I should deploy 2 application on tomcat server, one is only with HTML/CSS/JS but I should run spring-boot application on same tomcat. Now I copied war file to webapps/ (directory)

Comment: According to the logs, the application is deployed successfully - `Deployment of web application archive [makerscout-0.7.war] has finished in [53,213] ms`.

Comment: Yes, but When I access to /makerscout-0.7, 404 error comes up...

Comment: Ah, if you're deploying it with a load of associated HTML etc. I understand now. Sorry, I'm only used to deploying SpringBoot apps as standalone microservices.

Comment: I got it! thank you so much :]

Comment: For starters stop mixing Spring versions... Replace `spring-websocket` and `spring-messaging` with the `spring-boot-starter-websocket` and thyme leaf with `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`.

Comment: Could you include more logs? What's the port Tomcat is listening on? What's the url you are sending the request to? Is /makerscout-0.7 supposed to display a home / index page?

Comment: Thank you all, I solved this problem when I put SpringBootServletInitializer extension on bootApplication class. My bad..